# toLocaleString with timestamps

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to output a UNIX timestamp value in `en-GB` using `toLocaleString("en-GB")`.

```
var currentTimestamp = 1594859725;
console.log(new Date(currentTimestamp * 1000).toLocaleString("en-GB"));
```

For some reason the date format outputs in MM/DD/YY 00:00:00 format when I'm trying to output it in DD/MM/YY like "en-GB" should. Any help? :S

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in an options object and set the `dateStyle` property to "short" and the `timeStyle` property to "medium".

```js
var currentTimestamp = 1594859725;
console.log(new Date(currentTimestamp * 1000).toLocaleString("en-GB", {
    dateStyle: 'short', timeStyle: 'medium'
}));
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the date output but now its missing the actual time (00:00:00). Is there a way to have both?

Comment: Argument of type '{ dateSytle: string; timeStyle: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DateTimeFormatOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'dateStyle' does not exist in type 'DateTimeFormatOptions'.

Getting this error

Comment: @00kain Is that the result of running the snippet? What browser and version of it are you using?